# Rapache & R for leaflet

Tags: html, r, leaflet, raster, rapache

I'm trying to make a webpage with Rapache and "Leaflet for R". The main reason I did install Rapache is to use R inside of a html page (with brew). But, I cant figure out how to return my map inside the html page without saving it as a html extern file (which Rapache is useless). Lets take a exemple :

```
<%
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet()
m <- addTiles(m)
m <- addMarkers(m, lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m #Does not show anything
saveWidget(m, file = outPath, selfcontained = FALSE, libdir ='leafletwidget_libs') #work but not proper
%>
```

This is what I have in my html file and I would like to be able to return this map (m) and add it somewhere on my current page. The main reason I would like to do this is because I'm going to use this on a website and i would like it to be dynamic and not creating plenty of htmlfile. This is not really proper. Hope you can help me :) Thanks you !

Comment: what do you mean by #work but not proper

Comment: On the website I will have alot of different data to add on the map (raster-map) and this data can be added at anytime. So I think its better to not save plenty of html files

Comment: have you tried m <-  leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(data=m, lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R"); m; m should open in your browser

Comment: Yes, this is what i tried and and it work when I tape the code on R but on Rapache, it doesn't show anything (blank page)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this type of file on our web dashboards we create a space using iFrames which defines the area the swidget will load into, it has worked very well for us. Have you tried using iFrames?

[exapmple code to embed it with suggestions about folder management](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147023/how-do-i-embed-the-a-leaflet-map-into-my-web-page-using-qgis2leaf)

You can tweak the size of the frame using traditional front-end practices.